# What is this insect with rough brown shell on potatoes?

Tags: identification, insects, potatoes

This insect with a rough brownish shell showed up on potatoes at a friend's house in Vermont. I've looked around in books and online and can't find anything that's an exact match. Current control strategy is knocking them into a can of soapy water. (My friend hasn't said anything about them making a stink when removing them.)

Update via email:

> Yes, I've had a couple fly away.  Though they're very slow to get moving
>   (i.e. very easy to get into the soapy water first).  They're really stuck
>   to the leaves, so I have to really scrape them off the leaf.  You can't see
>   in the pic, but they leave big round holes (size of pencil eraser at their
>   biggest).

[image]

Comment: At the risk of being uninformative....it's a beetle, one of the over 400,000 species of them.

Comment: @kevinsky: You've at least managed to do better than my guess, which was completely in the wrong order...

Comment: I just wanted to say also that I hadn't seen anything about them needing to be removed particularly (there is one type of tortoise beetle that is considered a pest, but not this one) especially since we don't eat the leaves of potato plants. It depends on how much damage they are doing of course as it doesn't do a plant any good to have it's leaves eaten away!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a Tortoise Beetle (part of Leaf Beetle subfamily), probably Plagiometriona clavata - Common Garden Tortoise Beetle or Clavate Tortoise Beetle.
(The beetles as a group seem to have undergone a number of taxonomic and name changes)

See another excellent picture of one here: http://www.pbase.com/image/28969283

There is some more information about them from the University of Florida here:
http://entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/orn/beetles/Plagiometriona_clavata.htm

Also, anyone interested should google image search "tortoise beetles" because they look amazing :D